# Информация о Scene builder

Tags: java, scene-builder

Начал работать с интерфейсом Scene builder, подскажите, где найти информацию как и где прописывать, чтобы закрывалось окно, открывалось новое, дублировалось и т.п.

Comment: В Scene Builder - нигде. Это уже нужно прописывать в коде на Java (в контроллере, например).

Comment: @insolor, это я знаю, мне нужны команды